# PHPMailer - only first attachment is sent

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am adding attachments as follows:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
    if(file_exists($dir . $_FILES["file".$i]["tmp_name"])){

      $mail->AddAttachment($dir . $_FILES["file".$i]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file".$i]["name"]);
    }
}
```

Files are uploaded on server properly, but only first attachment is attached to the email. For second and third attachment I get error: `Could not access file: upload/`. I have have found that line `7 => 0` in `class.phpmailer.php` should be replaced with `7 => count($this->attachment)` but it did not help. Can you help me with this issue? TIA

Comment: Could this be an issue with file permissions?

Comment: All files have the same permissions, but only first file is attached. So I think there is an another problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error `"Could not access file: upload/"`, that suggests that `$_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]` and `$_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"]` are both empty/blank, and contain no values (otherwise it would say `"Could not access file: upload/foo.gif"`).

`echo` out these values to the screen and see if they're actually there. Better yet, use `print_r( $_FILES );` to see all the values in this array.

I suspect `file_exists` would return true even though the file names are blank, because `file_exists` also works on folders (i.e. `file_exists` is telling you the "upload/" folder exists).

**EDIT:** One other thing to mention, if you're using PHP 5.2.12 or better, check that [max_file_uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) in your INI settings isn't preventing you from uploading more than one file.

Comment: Ok, but how will you explain fact, that first file is attached correctly. I still don't understand why it works that way.

Comment: @mkas Have you done print_r on the `$_FILES` var? What do you see? Are the filenames for the other files there? Did you check to see if max_file_uploads allows you to upload more than 1 file at a time?